# Commutative ring satisfying a.c.c. and d.c.c. on radical ideals

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, krull-dimension, zariski-topology, local-rings

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity whose prime spectrum is both Noetherian and Artinian under Zariski topology i.e. $R$ satisfies a.c.c. and d.c.c. on radical ideals. Then is it true that $R$ has dimension zero ? If this is not true in general, is it true if we further assume $R$ is local ?

Comment: @user26857: Thanks for making my case in your comment ...

Comment: My apologies, close vote retracted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  For instance, any finite topological space is trivially both Noetherian and Artinian, but need not be zero-dimensional.  Explicitly, for instance, if $R$ is a discrete valuation ring then its spectrum has two points but is not zero-dimensional.